# How to change img style when checkbox is selected?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is my code

```
<div class="itemTaskUser">
  <input type="checkbox" name="users" id="user0" style="display: none">
  <label for="user0" class="checkbox-inline">
  <div>Rodolphe</div>
  <img src="rodo.jpg" class="avatar32" >
  </label>
</div>
```

What I try to acheive is to set up a CSS that will put a green border on img when the checkbox is selected

I tried with:

```
input:checked + label {
    color:green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
input:checked + img {
    border:2px solid green;
    width: 64px;
}
```

The label is green when checkbox is selected: GOOD

But nothing with image !

Any clue ?

Comment: I hope the answer helped you solve the problem. If yes, please consider marking it as "accepted".

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the code in question is that the `label` is the adjacent sibling of the `input` and not the `img` and so the second selector doesn't select any element.

The `+` is the [***adjacent sibling*** combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) which is used to select the element that is right next to the reference element in the DOM. Here the `label` is the immediate sibling of the `input` (the ***reference*** element) and the `img` ***is a child of the*** `label`, so using `input:checked + label img` will ***select the*** `img` ***that is a descendant of the*** `label` ***which in-turn is the adjacent sibling of a checked input***.

```css
input:checked + label {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
input:checked + label img {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemTaskUser">
  <input type="checkbox" name="users" id="user0" style="display: none">
  <label for="user0" class="checkbox-inline">
    <div>Rodolphe</div>
    <img src="rodo.jpg" class="avatar32">
  </label>
</div>
```

We can also use `input:checked + label > img` as the selector. This will narrow it down even further because the [`>` combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) will select the `img` ***only when it is a child*** of the `label` and not a grand-child or a great grand-child etc.